# Error processing SQL: TypeError: window.openDatabase is not a function

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, opendatabase

I have some strange issue in my code. i have create simple `DB_Function.js` to manage JS function inside html page.

i am calling function inside `<body onLoad="CALL_DB()">` so first that will initialize the DB and create table if needed.

**Issue is here ,**

- Working : Chrome
- Not Working : Android Mobile & Fire Fox

Code are as below :

**DB_Function.js**

```
function CALL_DB() {
    try {
        alert("call_db");
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    } catch (err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: " + err);
    }
}


function populateDB(tx) {
    try {
        alert("call_table");
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (3, "C")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (4, "K")');
    } catch (err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: " + err);
    }
}


function errorCB(tx, err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: " + err);
}

// Transaction success callback

function successCB() {
    alert("success!");
}
```

**Test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Storage Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/DB_function.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body onLoad="CALL_DB()">
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Database</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the my [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Mznr6/) 
Please help me i don't know where i am wrong.

Thanks for read my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was here,

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

I have address a live js file to load so might be they was not able to load while launch the application.

So, I have save it locally in `assets/www/js/cordova.js`.

So finally it looks like above  and its working for me perfectly.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using Web SQL Database, which is [not supported by Firefox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage). Also, the specification is [abandoned by the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/).

Have a look at [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/IndexedDB) ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb)) instead. There is also at least one [shim](https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim) to make IndexedDB work in browsers that only support Web SQL Database.

The code "works" in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mznr6/1/) on `Android Browser 4.1.2`.

Comment: After fixing your fiddle (script is executed in the onload already) http://jsfiddle.net/Mznr6/1/ it does work for me using the Android stock browser (old 4.1.2).

Comment: i have open your fiddle line and its showing me same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Look like your haven't initialize Cordova / PhoneGap API. You must first listen to deviceReady event prior to manipulate the APIs

Look at the following doc:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready