# Angular website works on Chrome, not Firefox or Safari

Tags: angular, web-sql, kinvey

I have a website served by `express` running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, Node.js 14.  Login and everything works fine on Chrome, but on Firefox I get `window.openDatabase is not a function` and on Safari I get `web sql is deprecated` when I try to login.  Website: https://www.portapay.xyz/login.  I am currently not building for production; how I build: `ng build --configuration development`.  I have made sure that all of my browsers are up to date and have the latest version.  None of the code I wrote uses `window.openDatabase` or `executeSql`.  I only connect to a MongoDB with [Kinvey's SDK](https://github.com/Kinvey/js-sdk/tree/master/packages/angular-sdk).  I do not use Cordova.

**browserlistrc**

```
last 1 Chrome version
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major versions
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
not IE 11 # Angular supports IE 11 only as an opt-in. To opt-in, remove the 'not' prefix on this line.
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": false,
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^12.2.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.2",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.14.5",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js": "^3.1.16",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^5.5.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^4.2.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^4.4.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^4.2.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^4.4.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^3.1.6",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^4.8.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-indicators": "^1.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^6.7.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^2.3.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-notification": "^2.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^2.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^3.0.7",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-ripple": "^2.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^2.1.6",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.5",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.11.0",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^4.41.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "^9.1.15",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.17.1",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.34",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.172",
    "@types/loglevel": "^1.6.3",
    "@types/request-ip": "0.0.37",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "@types/winston-loggly-bulk": "^3.0.1",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "easy-pie-chart": "^2.1.7",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^6.0.0-alpha.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.0",
    "inactivity-countdown-timer": "^2.0.0-beta-2",
    "kinvey-angular-sdk": "^5.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mdb-angular-ui-kit": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^8.0.1",
    "ngx-animate": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-logger": "^4.3.3",
    "ngx-spinner": "^9.0.2",
    "ngx-stripe": "^9.3.0",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^11.0.0",
    "request-ip": "^2.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "screenfull": "^3.3.3",
    "stripe": "^8.170.0",
    "terser": "^4.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "winston-loggly-bulk": "^3.2.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

Comment: Are you using " Web SQL Database"?. Here says that is deprecated, and only works on Chrome. But it also has a solution, put the whole rute in the script of cordova (I don't know if you use it too). Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605614/error-processing-sql-typeerror-window-opendatabase-is-not-a-function

Comment: @JuanBerzosaTejero none of the code I wrote uses any kind of SQL database connection; I cannot speak for all of the packages in my `package.json`; I should try to figure out where this error is coming from, it is just difficult when everything is compiled; I use [Kinvey's SDK](https://github.com/Kinvey/js-sdk/tree/master/packages/angular-sdk) for a cloud database connection to their MongoDB backend

Comment: It's Kinvey alright `var db = window.openDatabase(dbName, 1, 'Kinvey WebSQL', SIZE);`

Comment: @BojanKogoj shoot, you're right; [permalink](https://github.com/Kinvey/js-sdk/blob/8c714e749e64ae11f7d231c67fc8570480678166/tests/integration/specs/html5/init.spec.js#L57); I will open an issue with them as Web SQL is deprecated; thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is related to Kinvey.  It does not apply to Angular.

Comment: @Patrick I updated my tags to include kinvey though?  I added the answer and this question is not likely to get any more activity for years

Comment: @xinthose I retracted the close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinvey support replied to me, apparently, you have to set your `storage` type when initializing `KinveyModule` in the `imports` of `app.module.ts`.  `WebSQL` is the current default if it is not set.  [Kinvey Documentation](https://devcenter.kinvey.com/angular2/guides/getting-started#configure-your-app).

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { KinveyModule, StorageProvider } from 'kinvey-angular-sdk';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    KinveyModule.init({
      appKey: '<appKey>',
      appSecret: '<appSecret>',
      storage: StorageProvider.IndexedDB
    })
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`IndexedDB` is the replacement for `WebSQL` from what I could find [online](https://caniuse.com/?search=indexeddb).